# htaccess - How to restrict to access from my home

Tags: apache, macos, .htaccess, ip-address

I have a website on the internet that I only want to be accessible from my house.

Could I have htaccess be restricted to the MAC address of my router?  If not, are there any other options?

I don't think I could use IP address because my ISP changes it all the time.

Comment: If you only want access from a single network (i.e. your home) then why not put the site on that network rather than the internet? Is this for testing purposes?

Comment: Or the good old password, so you can also access it from elsewhere.

Comment: I wantd the same thing and this is what worked for me

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91701/ufw-allow-traffic-only-from-a-domain-with-dynamic-ip-address

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the MAC because it won't get past the next router. Usually, even if you have a dynamic IP, your ISP gives you a hostname that is fixed, something like `customer1337.newyork.bestisp.com`. [See what it is here](http://www.displaymyhostname.com/), and use that in the htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot use your MAC address or your IP Address, your best solution is to use DNS to maintain a host record. You can use [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/) or freedns to set up a dynamic dns record. Many routers these days actually allow you to configure your router to ping these sites to update your host record.

Suppose on freedns.afraid.org you set it up so that gregmyhome.mooo.com points to your router. Then you can update the htaccess file to allow access from that hostname. Apache will perform a reverse dns lookup upon your visiting the site, and let you in.

I will say, however, that there may be a delay which may cause you to be restricted for some time. This problem may force you to look to other authentication mechanisms, such as digest auth, client certificate, or even [ssh tunnelling](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Bart, you could just use a .htpasswd file and set a username and password for the site, so that only you can login.

Answer (score 0):

you probably could but that's not what htaccess is for, in my opinion. unless you set up authentication *using* htaccess. but then your website will be accessible from everywhere that has the password.

iptables can do mac address filtering though. why don't you set that up?

so if your router's mac is xyz,

first set the default policy:

`iptables -P INPUT DROP`

then specifically allow yours:

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp –destination-port 80 -m mac –mac-source xyz -j ACCEPT`

Comment: the mac address wouldn't make it to the remote server.